# Ошибка при запуске проекта Spring WebFlow

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, glassfish

При запуске проекта получаю ошибку

> The Eclipse plugin cannot communicate with the GlassFish server....

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте наличие правильных настроек для GlassFish и самого GlasFish

`Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments`

Comment: я проверю, как появится первая возможность, спасибо.